# Firefox addon: how to send current url to backgroundscript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm Writing a firefox addon that logs the current URL when pressing the addon icon at the toolbar.

When pressing the button, a background script will call the native app. That native app should write the current URL to a txt file. At this point, I'm able to write the text file when hitting the addon button. I'm able to write the contents of a variable created in background.js to a text file. But I can't pass the current URL to the background script.

The addon is based on the example addons from Mozilla:
https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/native-messaging

When using `var url = window.location.href;`I get the URL/Location of the loaded script.

**Question**: How can I pass the current URL to the background.js, so it will write the URL to a text file?

Below are the scripts:
Code background.js:

```
var url = window.location.href;

/*
On startup, connect to the "ping_pong" app.
*/
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");

/*
Listen for messages from the app.
*/
port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  console.log("Received: " + response);
});

/*
On a click on the browser action, send the app a message.
*/
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Console logger");
  port.postMessage(url);
});
```

Code Manifest.json

```
{

  "description": "ping_pong",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Native messaging start Python",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/message.svg"
  },

  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "ping_pong@example.org",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/message.svg"
  },
  
  "permissions": ["nativeMessaging"]
```